# multiple divs affecting the banner div

Tags: html, css

i want my banner("affected") to change whenever I hover at another div,
each div will display a different effect on my banner("affected").

```
 <div class="hover-container">
  this is the hover container
<div class="hover-me">hover me</div>
<div class="square1">hover me</div>
<div class="square2">hover me</div>
<div class="square3">hover me</div>
<div class="square4">hover me</div>
<div class="square5">hover me</div>
<div class="square6">hover me</div>
<div class="square7">hover me</div>
<div class="square8">hover me</div>
<div class="square9">hover me</div>
</div>

<div class="affected">
  affected
</div>
```

my css is

```
.hover-container:hover ~ .affected{
 background:pink;
}
   .square1:hover ~ .affected{
 background:blue;
}
```

...till square9...
then

```
.hover-container{
  pointer-events:none;
}

.hover-me, .square1, .square2, .square3, .square4, .square5, .square6, 
.square7, .square8, .square9{
  pointer-events:auto;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: whats not working with your code?

Comment: when I hover at square8, the banner should turn pink but it does not.

Comment: works fine for me, but the code you provide is missing a closing div tag

Comment: Your `.hover-container` class is missing an ending `</div>`. If your `.affected` class is outside of `.hover-container` your sibling selectors won't work as intended because the squares aren't siblings of affected.

Comment: sorry, I'm new here. it has ending tag but not included here, lemme edit the post

Comment: .affected is only a sibling of .hover-container, not a sibling of .square1 to 9, so it will always be pink, if you move div.affected inside .hover-container it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to be working correctly. Maybe this helps?

```css
.square9:hover~.affected {
  background: blue;
}

.square8:hover~.affected {
  background: red;
}

.square8,
.square9 {
  background: #eeeeee;
}

div {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hover-container {
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hover-me,
.square1,
.square2,
.square3,
.square4,
.square5,
.square6,
.square7,
.square8,
.square9 {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-container">
  <div class="square8">hover me</div>
  <div class="square9">hover me</div>

  <div class="affected">
    affected
  </div>
</div>
```